# C++, compile time error "no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'someClass*' and 'someClass')"

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers, parameter-passing

OS: Windows 7 64bit
IDE: Qt Creator 5.7.0 (32 bit)
Compiler: MinGW 5.3.0 (32 bit)

As a foreword, this is an exercise to help me understand some pointers/classes mechanics, thus `bool no = 1;`, I dont wanna use `<vector>`s nor any other `easyToUse` tools.

I'm trying to pass an [array of pointers to `someClass` type objects] as an argument of a function.
The whole code is too long, to paste it all here, so I'll just post a simplified version of the parts that are related to the error(s).

Here's the code (the relevant parts):

```
class someClass
{
public:
    someClass(){;}
    someClass(unsigned int classConstructorArgIn);
    ~someClass(){;}
}


someClass:someClass(unsigned int classConstructorArgIn)
{
    //does stuff
}


void theFunction(someClass *arClassesIn, unsigned int arElementsIn);


int main()
{
    unsigned int arElements = someOperationsResult; //cant really write down how I calculate this value, you can test it with a const value, if you have to
    someClass *arClasses[arElements] = {0}; //array of pointers to instances of someClass (allegedly!)

    theFunction(arClasses[arElements], arElements); //BTW::I had to write the argument this way, otherwise it says the definition doesnt match any declaration
    //Furthermore, I dont understand what kind of value I should actually type in there, whether the index of the first element (0) or the size of the array (arElements)

    return 0;
}


void theFunction(someClass *arClassesIn, unsigned int arElementsIn)
{
    unsigned int classConstructorArg = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arElements; i++)
    {
        classConstructorArg = someOtherOperationsResult;
        arClassesIn[(someClass)i] = new someClass(classConstructorArg); //ERROR::"no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'someClass*' and 'someClass')"
        //For some reason that I dont understand, I had to cast the [i]ndex to (someClass) type, otherwise I get a whole bunch of errors about type conversion
    }
}
```

Comment: *I dont wanna use <vector>s nor any other easyToUse tools* -- You still have to write the program, regardless if the tool is "easy" or not.  It's not as if using `vector` will magically write the program for you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why, didnt I write it? `<vector>`s are supposed to make the use of arrays easier and safer, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Really, even if you go for a [mcve] by removing things that don't affect the error, one possibility is that you end up with something like `class someClass {}; someClass obj = new someClass();`. It gives you the same error as using `i` for the index (which is the more logical approach as you said, and both that and casting to `someClass` give errors, so...) That said, having it be two lines makes it much easier to see why it fails.

Comment: @chris You mean the compiler might give me that kind of error because of a misplaced semicolon?

Comment: @ZehryoKarham, There's no misplaced semicolon. The error should be identical to the one from the array element assignment because that's basically what it's trying to do. At that point, it's also easier to realize that the array element is not a pointer, as you'd like it to be.

Comment: @ZehryoKarham -- Yes it makes the code more safer, but you still have to write the code to use them correctly.  It isn't as if all you need to do is `#include <vector>` and things become ok.  Still have to put in the design time, logic, etc. into the program.

Comment: @chris That function, in its complete form, is member of a class that has its own .cpp file, and it's about 500 lines long. The whole program is about 1000 lines long, impossible to post it all here. ^^

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Several days of notes and natural language transpositions of the operations, before starting to code it. And now it's about 1000 lines long. Plenty of design time and logic, compared to my usual exercises. ^^'

Comment: I still cant understand why I got a -1 on my question. It's not a double, it includes code and it's exposed in an orderly fashion. Is it because it's too silly for the experts, or it's because it's not intriguing enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `void theFunction(someClass *arClassesIn, unsigned int arElementsIn);`, `arClassesIn` is a pointer to an object of type `someClass`.
However, it looks like you want to pass an array of pointers. So you must change your function to:

```
void theFunction(someClass **arClassesIn, unsigned int arElementsIn);
// Or
void theFunction(someClass *arClassesIn[], unsigned int arElementsIn);
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
theFunction(arClasses, arElements);
```

And also replace

```
arClassesIn[(someClass)i] = new someClass(classConstructorArg);
```

by

```
arClassesIn[i] = new someClass(classConstructorArg);
```

---

What is wrong with your code:

1.

```
theFunction(arClasses[arElements], arElements);
```

`arClasses[arElements]` is invalid. `arClasses` is an array of size `arElements`, so valid indexes range from `0` to `arElements - 1`. Accessing any other index (like `arElements`) can lead to crashes.

2.

```
 arClassesIn[(someClass)i] = new someClass(classConstructorArg);
```

As `arClassesIn` is of type `someClass *` and you cast `i` to `someClass` the compiler looks for a function like:

```
someClass operator[](someClass *a, someClass b)
```

Such a function does not exist in your code, that's why you have this error (`ERROR::"no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'someClass*' and 'someClass')`).

You do NOT have to cast `i` to access an array element. Your previous errors were probably caused because `arClassesIn[i]` is of type `someClass` while  `new someClass(classConstructorArg)` is of type `someClass *`. This is fixed by changing the prototype of `theFunction` as stated above.

Comment: Yesssss!!! It works! I'm not sure why it has to work this way. Maybe because it's an array of pointers and not just an array? I guess so.
Anyway, the error reported by the compiler is an utter non-sense, how am I supposed to understand what went wrong?!

Comment: @ZehryoKarham : how is it "utter non-sense"? `someClass*` and `someClass**` are distinct types.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add some explanations. On a side note if you do not understand why it works this way, you should look at some C tutorials on pointer and arrays.

Comment: @BenjaminT with just `[i]`, the compiler would complain that I was using an `unsigned int` index to search through a `someClass` type array. So I did the most logical thing (to me), I casted i to the type the compiler was looking for. Seemingly, that error was the result of the arguments-passing error, not one in its own. Mayhem in my brains! x) EDIT: I did google around, and a LOT, but for the error given by the compiler, rather than the "array of pointers as argument" thing. ^^'

Comment: @ZehryoKarham, What was the exact error with `[i]`? I have no idea which error you're talking about.

Comment: @chris The actual error (as Benjamin pointed out before) was the way I was passing the array of pointers as an argument for the function. It lacked the `[]` operand, which would tell the function that it was an array of pointers and not just a pointer (had to be `someClass *arClassesIn[]` instead of `someClass *arClassesIn`). Because of that error, `[i]` was subsequently interpreted in the wrong way by the compiler, which brought me to try solving it by casting `i` to the `someClass` type (now I can see the horror....error!).

Comment: @ZehryoKarham, I know that, but your description of the error (using an unsigned int index to search through a someClass type array) doesn't match any compiler errors I can think of off the top of my head. I'm curious what the exact text is.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar The error is about the `[]` operator and then it mentions the object types `someClass` and `someClasses*`. I couldnt see any connection, between the two things, also because I didnt even have anything like a `someClass` object at all, just pointers to instances. I'm a beginner, very little is needed to throw me at the bottom of a well of confusion.